# PCA application on MNIST Dataset: Memory Error

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca

I'm trying to apply the PCA algorithm to compress the MNIST handwritten dataset in order to improve my Neural Network performance. So I wrote this function in python3:

```py
def pca(X, K):
    m, n = X.shape
    sigma = (1/m) * X.T @ X
    U, S, V = numpy.linalg.svd(sigma)
    U = U[:, :K]
    Z = X @ U
    return (Z, U)
```

Since the original dataset is really large, I'm getting a memory error in:

```
sigma = (1/m) * X.T @ X
```

I tried feature scaling to solve this issue, but it didn't work.

edit: In my test runs, m and n values are 70000 and 784, respectively.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! By default, I don't see why a `784x784` covariance matrix wouldn't fit into memory. Please share values of `m, n` and the amount of memory you have available at the machine where you run the script.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce you issue. On my ageing HP ProBook 4670 with 4G RAM, I get the covariance matrix in about 5 seconds, no errors. Try passing in smaller chunks to find out when you run out of memory. Side issue: You should probably not estimate a feature transformation on the test data.